# Morphia - using hasAllOf and hasThisElement together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia, mongodb-java

I have a mongo collection named 'comment' which has documents which have a structure similar to this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("9873214jkhdkfjdsf8324"),
"nm" : "test",
"sts" : 1,
"updby" : NumberLong(0),
"tags" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "women", 
        "rank" : 1, 
        "type" : 3 
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "men",
        "rank" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "clothing",
        "rank" : 2,
        "type" : 1
    }
]
```

I want to query the collection using a mongo query which would look like this :

```
db.comment.find({"tags":{
        $all:[
                 {"$elemMatch":{"name" : "women", "type" : 3}}, 
                 {"$elemMatch":{"name" : "clothing"}}   
        ]}
        })
```

The number of subdocuments I match inside the 'tags' will be variable. In the above query I am trying to match 2 sets of combinations.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
TagsDo tag = new TagsDo("women", null, 3);

            Query<CommentDo> t =
                    getMongoDAORead().getDatastore()
                    .createQuery(CommentDoImpl.class)
                    .field("tags").hasThisElement(tag).disableValidation();
```

This would form the following mongo query :

```
{"ctags":{"$elemMatch":{"name":"women","type":3}}}
```

Now to have more than one combination, I try to create a list of TagsDo:

```
List<TagsDo> tag = new ArrayList<TagsDo>();
TagsDo tag1 = new TagsDo("women", null, 3);
TagsDo tag2 = new TagsDo("clothing", null, 1);

Query<CommentDo> t =
                getMongoDAORead().getDatastore()
                .createQuery(CommentDoImpl.class)
                .field("tags").hasThisElement(Arrays.asList(tag.toArray)).disableValidation();
```

This forms the following mongo query :

```
{ "ctags" : 
     { "$elemMatch" : [ { "className" : "com.dal.comments.TagsDo" , "name" : "handbags" , "type" : 3} , 
                        { "className" : "com.dal.comments.TagsDo" , "name" : "web" , "type" : 0}]}}
```

I have one problem above,

-> The 'elemMatch' should appear twice and not just once.

---

After that is done, I need to use 'hasAllOf' which will add the '$alll' keyword to the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Morphia - Query based on a subdocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672758/morphia-query-based-on-a-subdocument)

Comment: @evanchooly: I already resolved that and have closed that. This question is different in the way that it adds more to the previous question and I wanted both of the questions to be separate as I found a solution to the previous one already.

Comment: Fair enough.  It's just the fourth time i've seen this question in different forums.  :)

Comment: Doesn't that say a lot about how much of a hard time I am having to figure out the solution to this...:)

Comment: Not particularly since I've already answered in one of those forums.

Comment: Well that was a different question and I think I din't frame the question correctly back then. The current question is exactly how my problem looks like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47354/discussion-between-pi-horse-and-evanchooly)