# How to write the following query in morphia

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia

Can someone help me out in writing the below query in morphia. Thanks

```
db.restaurants.find({grades : { $elemMatch:{"score":{$gt : 80 , $lt :100}}}});
```

based on my study of morphia i used the below. but it is not correct

```
List<Restaurant_M> r = ds.find(Restaurant_M.class)
                         .field("grades.score").lessThan(100)
                         .field("grades.score").greaterThan(80)
                         .asList();
```

Comment: Based on https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#methods — what did you try already?

Comment: I would have expected that to work, but the docs also suggest `ds.createQuery(MyEntity.class).filter("foo >", 12).filter("foo <", 30);` — might give that a try. And you're getting the wrong results?

Comment: no. both of these statements are equivalent to db.restaurants.find({$and : [{"grades.score" : {$gt:80}},{"grades.score" : {$lt:100}}]}) this checks for the validity of both the conditions individually but doesnt ensure that they are bw 80-100.

Comment: What do you mean? You'll only get docs greater than 80 and lower than 100, which should boil down to between 80 and 100 (since the two conditions are and connected)

Comment: yes, i will get docs where the score in the grades subdocument is above 80 and where the score is below 100. but if there is a score in a grade which is 131 that will return too. bcoz it satisfies the > 80 condition. this is the query which i posted in the comments. the query which i posted in the question is the correct way to do a lt or gt in an array (subdocument) but i cannot figure out how to do it in morphia. you can try running both the mongodb queries. the collection can be downloaded from http://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/retaurants.zip

Comment: See a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691198/morphia-using-hasallof-and-hasthiselement-together

Comment: @NicCottrell that gives the solution for find an exact element in an array, not a range of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after banging my head against the walls of morphia for a week i am assuming there is no way to do this in morphia almost every code i write in morphia gives a query of type

```
query: { $and: [ { grades: { $elemMatch: { score: { $gt: 80 } } } }, { grades: { $elemMatch: { score: { $lt: 100 } } } } ] }
```

this only ensures that every individual score in the grades array is either more than 80 or less than 100. so if a document had a grade with a score of 131 it would still be returned. My objective was to get only those documents where all the score in the grades sub-document were between 80 and 100. The query posted in the question achieved this but i was not able to translate it into morphia

Resorting to the java driver i have been able to do this. see the below code

```
Bson f1 = Filters.gt("score", 80);
Bson f2 = Filters.lt("score", 100);
Bson f3 = and (f1, f2);
MongoCursor<Document> c = collection.find(
            elemMatch("grades", f3))
                                    .iterator();
```

still, if anyone finds a way to do this in morphia i would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use Morphia's filter(...) method with the 'elem' operator to get the behavior you require. See https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query

Answer (score 0):

I just added a new `elemMatch()` that addresses this issue.  You can try a snapshot build of Morphia or wait for the 1.3 release.

https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/pull/985